# commands after read in shell script gives error

Tags: bash, shell, user-input

I am creating shell script to take the input path from user and copy a particular file to inputted path. Below is simple script to recover corrupted file and copy it to required path given by user

```
FILE=$1
bzip2recover $FILE
find . -name 'rec*bz2' -exec sh -c 'bzip2 -t "$0" 2>/dev/null || rm -f $0' {} \;
cat rec* > $FILE
rm -f rec*
read -p "Enter your path to copy :" PATH
cp $FILE $PATH
rm -f $FILE
```

lines after `read` gives error like `cp : command not found` and `rm : command not found`. What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting crucial system variable `PATH` with user's input. `PATH` normally points to folders with executables. After you overwrite it with user input, system is no longer able to find executables.

Use some different variable name.

Comment: That's so silly mistake made by me. anyway thanks for pointing out that.